# Active menu item based on URL and ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navigation

I want to have active menu items in my navigation based on URL and ID, **not href**. None of the available solutions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593591/jquery-active-class-to-menu-item-based-on-current-url) , or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040221/set-menu-item-active-based-on-url)) worked for me.

My Navigation looks like this

```
<nav id="PageNavigation">
    <div class="nav_ebene_2">
        <div role="button" class="nav-item" id="P_Bogendaten.aspx?IDNavi=194">
            <p>menu item 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The URL, if clicked on `menu item 1`, is `https://example.de/App_AspxFiles/P_Bogendaten.aspx?IDNavi=194`. I want to add the class `menuactive` to the parent element (div which includes `nav_ebene_2`)

I need to compare the `id` with the current url, if it matches, add `menuactive`. This would be my way, but the if conditions is never true.

```
  var currenturl  = window.location.href
  for (const div of document.querySelectorAll("#PageNavigation nav-item")) {
    if (div.id == currenturl ) {
      div.parentElement.classList.add("activemenu");
    }
  }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to avoid `parentElement`, one day you might want to change slightly your HTML and the JS will fail. Use the [more flexible `.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the URI from the `window.location`

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = params.get("IDNavi");

console.log(id) // "194"
```

**or...** if you have a URI address already as **String**

```js
const uriString = "https://example.de/App_AspxFiles/P_Bogendaten.aspx?IDNavi=194";
const id = new URL(uriString).searchParams.get("IDNavi");

console.log(id); // "194"
```

now that you extracted the desired ID, all it takes is **to target the desired Element** like i.e:

```js
const EL_id = document.querySelector(`[id$="IDNavi=${id}"]`);
```

where the Attribute Selector `[]` is querying the DOM for an Element which `id` ends `$=` in `IDNavi=194`

Then, to **get its parent** use the Element's [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method:

```js
const EL_id_parent = EL_id.closest(".nav_ebene_2");
```

and finally you can **add the desired *active* class**

```js
EL_id_parent.classList.add("activemenu");
```

***Demo time:***
Make class *active* an element with ID ending in a specific query param value:

```js
const uriString = "https://example.de/App_AspxFiles/P_Bogendaten.aspx?IDNavi=194";
const id = new URL(uriString).searchParams.get("IDNavi");

/*
// you should use this instead, the above is for this DEMO only 
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = params.get("IDNavi");
*/

const EL_id = document.querySelector(`[id$="IDNavi=${id}"]`);
const EL_id_parent = EL_id.closest(".nav_ebene_2");
EL_id_parent.classList.add("activemenu");
```

```css
.activemenu {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<nav id="PageNavigation">
  <div class="nav_ebene_2">
    <div role="button" class="nav-item" id="P_Bogendaten.aspx?IDNavi=194">
      <p>IDNavi=194</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_ebene_2">
    <div role="button" class="nav-item" id="P_Bogendaten.aspx?IDNavi=195">
      <p>IDNavi=195</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```